# Using Python to solve matrix equations to return corresponding arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

We want to write the above equations in matrix form as `F = Kx - b`. Write a function that takes the ki and Li values as inputs in 1-D arrays and returns the arrays corresponding to K and b.

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy import linalg
import numpy.linalg as np_linalg
import scipy.linalg as sp_linalg

def matrixform(ki, Li):
    K=np.zeros((len(ki),len(ki))) #empty matrices
    b=np.zeros(len(ki))
    for i in range(len(ki)): #filling in the k matrix
        for j in range(len(ki)):
            if i == j:
                K[i][j]=sum(ki[i:]*Li[i+1:])
            else:
                K[i][j]=ki[j]*Li[i+1]*np.exp(-sum(ki[i+1:j]*Li[i+1:j+1]))

    for i in range(len(ki)): #filling in b vector
        b[i]=ki[i]*Li[i]

    return K, b
```

The problem is that ki and Li are both supposed to be 4x1 arrays, but it is only working right now if ki is a 4x1 and Li is a 3x1.

This is the error that I am getting:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,).

Comment: pandas / numpy already support matrix operations. Do you really need a for-loop?

Comment: Please also provide the code used to call this function, including the definitions of ki and Li

Comment: And full error message